# Example for children of common sense in the Bible

Tags: bible, children

I'm looking for one or more examples, preferably stories, of common sense in the Bible. This is for teaching church children, aged 5-8. Ideally, the story will involve peer pressure, and someone resisting going along with the group.

There are examples of foolishness which I could use, eg:

- [Aaron and the Golden Calf](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2032&version=NLT)
- [Rehoboam's revolt](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings+12&version=NLT)

and numerous others but I'm looking for the opposite, a wise decision. I'm trying to find a situation that children can relate to, so eg [Solomon judging between two women](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%203:16-28&version=NLT) wouldn't work. And though I say wise, I'm looking for more like "common sense". That is, sometimes we just need to use the brain God has given us and not wait for Divine Inspiration.

Any stories fit this?

Comment: Perhaps giving examples of 'wisdom' would be much better, as 'common sense' is a western cultural concept - not a biblical one (and thus all attempts to find it in the Bible would be anachronistic and eisegetical).

Comment: @Dan: thanks for that, if that is true it undermines my question. However, what about [Psalm 32:9](http://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Psalm%2032%3A9) which seems to require that we use our common sense.

Comment: In context, that verse has to do with following the Lord versus not being led astray into sin (read the entire psalm). Again, the concept of 'common sense' would have been foreign to the psalmist. Don't be [an eisegete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisegesis), rather, exegete the text. Start with the text and ask what it says, don't look for a text to support what you want to say (proof-text). The Bible has *nothing* to say about some topics, and that's okay ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the stories of Daniel and his friends where they didn't give in to peer pressure? How about 1 Samuel where Jonathan sides with the David instead of his jealous father? And the story of Joseph where he made the right choice?

Comment: The Daniel story is a great idea, thanks. I also like I the Jonathan story idea. But which Joseph? There are three! Would you please also link to the verses?

Comment: Haha sorry I meant Joseph the son of Jacob. Maybe you could explain to the kids that the wife of Joseph's master was trying to tempt Joseph? But on second thought I think that might be too hard to explain to young children in an appropriate way.

Comment: Exactly, the might generate too many age inappropriate questions... :) Thanks for clarification. If you add links to verses and remove the reference to Joseph I will accept this answer.