# Is there a good example of believers seeking out advice from other believers in the Bible, especially one that is a story children would understand?

Tags: bible, children

I am [also](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19221/good-example-of-common-sense-in-the-bible) looking for an example of believers (Old Testament Jews or New Testament Christians) getting advice from other believers. Again, this is for teaching children aged 5-8 so ideally it will be a story to which they can relate.

There are individual verses that help eg:

- [Proverbs 12:15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%2012:15&version=NLT)
- [Proverbs 15:22](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%2015:22&version=NLT)

but a story is better. I briefly considered the [council at Jerusalem](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2015&version=NLT) which is a story but I don't think children could relate to it.

Comment: If you vote to close, would you please explain why?

Comment: It is too broad. There are too many possible answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would offer 1 Samuel also, but specifically [1 Sam 3:1-10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20sam%203:1-10&version=ESV) in which Samuel as a child receives advice from Eli on responding to God's call.

Comment: Welcome to the site! For all new visitors, I typically recommend a trip to the [Help Page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), but I see you're already a StackExchange user so I'll skip that.  I do recommend reading  [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer), since most people mistake the purpose of this particular site.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest (or at least to my mind most obvious) illustration of this point is that of Jesus himself.  When he was 12, he famously ditched his parents and went to the temple.

Luke (2:46) records a little detail that I think makes all the difference:

> After three days they found him in the temple courts, sitting among the teachers, listening to them and asking them questions.

This is God, asking the priests questions.  If He can do that, I feel very comfortable following his example.

Comment: I think that this, together with your edit to the question (which I rolled back) implies that we have a miscommunication. I want to have an example *to teach children* - it doesn't necessarily have to be *about children* - but that's a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

I like the story of Saul seeking out the Witch of Endor from [1 Samuel 28](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Samuel%2028&version=NIV).

Saul had become desperate to hear the wisdom that God would offer him, but the Lord had long since stopped talking to Saul. So Saul broke the law and sought out a medium to summon Samuel for him.

The story shows that you cannot only accept Godly wisdom when *you think* you need it. A good Christian would strive to learn new wisdom daily and consult the Lord and other, wiser Christians on every issue.

Comment: Isn't this about seeking out an *unbeliever*? Great story though, just not sure it answers my question.

Comment: @Wikis Saul sought out the only thing he had available to him. He first sought out the Lord through dreams, Urim, and prophets, but the Lord had cut him off because of his wickedness. Saul then proves his wickedness by seeking out the medium. Samuel, certainly a believer, is who he ends up talking to, which is who he was hoping to talk to all along.

Comment: My thanks for the answer and explanation. I don't think this will work for the children I have in mind; it raises all sorts of other issues like, *"so, we're allowed to contact dead people?"* - I don't want to go there.

Comment: @Wikis I thought you might say that. That is generally why people will not discuss this story. Also, there is a lot of debate on whether the figure was even Samuel in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that is also true - was it Samuel? So this story won't work for me, sorry.

Comment: @fredsbend just an FYI since you've got the only answer here that was posted post bounty, the bounty was created in error and was promptly requested to be removed. I've removed it in good faith, please let me know if you've got any issue.

Comment: @waxeagle With removing the bounty? No problem here. It's not like there was a whole lot of effort thrown into this post.

Comment: @fredsbend: it was [placed in error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198028/how-does-one-correct-the-question-on-which-a-bounty-was-placed).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few other ones not named so far.

Exodus 18 New King James Version (NKJV)
Jethro’s Advice

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+18&version=NKJV

Acts 8:26-40  Philip and the Ethiopian Eunuch comes to mind.

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+8%3A26-40&version=ESV